# How can I know that my Universal Analytics syntax is correct?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Since we added GA events to our webapp we lost bounce rate in our signup page. I [found](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) that adding "nonInteraction" key should make the trick but since I added it bounce rate is still 0.

Here it is what Analytic Debugger Add On, tell us what we are sending:

```
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: http://fb.me/react-devtools
Download the React DevTools for a better development experience: http://fb.me/react-devtools
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
Initializing Google Analytics.
Running command: ga("create", "UA-45345323-1", "app.wizeline.com", {siteSpeedSampleRate: 100})
Creating new tracker: t0
Running command: ga("set", "forceSSL", true)
Running command: ga("send", "pageview", {page: "#/signup", title: "signup", nonInteraction: 1})
Setting throttling cookie: "_gat"

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j36d&a=1180036341&t=pageview&ni=1&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.wizeline.com%2F&dp=%23%2Fsignup&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=signup&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1920x502&je=1&fl=17.0%20r0&_u=QAEAAQABI~&jid=552286626&cid=1169363107.1416505139&tid=UA-45345323-1&_r=1&z=1165069347


_j1              (&jid) 552286626
adSenseId        (&a)   1180036341
apiVersion       (&v)   1
clientId         (&cid) 1169363107.1416505139
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
flashVersion     (&fl)  17.0 r0
hitType          (&t)   pageview
javaEnabled      (&je)  1
language         (&ul)  en-us
location         (&dl)  https://app.wizeline.com/
nonInteraction   (&ni)  1
page             (&dp)  #/signup
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1080
title            (&dt)  signup
trackingId       (&tid) UA-45345323-1
viewportSize     (&vp)  1920x502
Running command: ga("send", "event", "signup", "view", "form_viewed", {nonInteraction: 1}, undefined)

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j36d&a=1180036341&t=event&ni=1&_s=2&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.wizeline.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Wizeline&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1920x502&je=1&fl=17.0%20r0&ec=signup&ea=view&el=form_viewed&_u=QAEAAQABI~&jid=&cid=1169363107.1416505139&tid=UA-45345323-1&z=2130626078


_j1              (&jid) 
adSenseId        (&a)   1180036341
apiVersion       (&v)   1
clientId         (&cid) 1169363107.1416505139
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
eventAction      (&ea)  view
eventCategory    (&ec)  signup
eventLabel       (&el)  form_viewed
flashVersion     (&fl)  17.0 r0
hitType          (&t)   event
javaEnabled      (&je)  1
language         (&ul)  en-us
location         (&dl)  https://app.wizeline.com/
nonInteraction   (&ni)  1
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1080
title            (&dt)  Wizeline
trackingId       (&tid) UA-45345323-1
viewportSize     (&vp)  1920x502

Sent beacon:
v=1&_v=j36d&a=1180036341&t=timing&_s=3&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.wizeline.com%2F&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=Wizeline&sd=24-bit&sr=1920x1080&vp=1920x502&je=1&fl=17.0%20r0&plt=6854&pdt=2&dns=0&rrt=508&srt=217&tcp=40&dit=5126&clt=5126&_u=QAEAAQABI~&jid=&cid=1169363107.1416505139&tid=UA-45345323-1&z=1698011418


_j1              (&jid) 
adSenseId        (&a)   1180036341
apiVersion       (&v)   1
clientId         (&cid) 1169363107.1416505139
encoding         (&de)  UTF-8
flashVersion     (&fl)  17.0 r0
hitType          (&t)   timing
javaEnabled      (&je)  1
l1               (&plt) 6854
l2               (&pdt) 2
l3               (&dns) 0
l4               (&rrt) 508
l5               (&srt) 217
l6               (&tcp) 40
l7               (&dit) 5126
l8               (&clt) 5126
language         (&ul)  en-us
location         (&dl)  https://app.wizeline.com/
screenColors     (&sd)  24-bit
screenResolution (&sr)  1920x1080
title            (&dt)  Wizeline
trackingId       (&tid) UA-45345323-1
viewportSize     (&vp)  1920x502
Inspectlet: fatal error: wid has not been set.
```

It shows both "nonInteraction" keys but again it does not let our bounce rate to increase from 0.

Any idea/misreading/wrong syntax I'm doing?

Thanks!

Comment: For one thing, pageviews cannot be set with a non  interaction flag.

Comment: Thank you @nyuen. I'll remove it. On the other hand is there a way to test that the data send was successful?

Comment: You can check in your Real-Time reports (make sure you are not filtering out your own visits). But it looks like, from the debugger output, everything is being sent, even the pageviews.....